# calling constructor with generic parameter instead of explicit

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I assume this question is duplicated.
But I could not find this question on SO

I want to instantiate a generic class. But if there is a constructor with a 
explicit parameter And the generic constructor also has that parameter due to the given type, the constructor with the explicit parameter is used.

Example

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Example<string> test = new Example<string>("test");
       test.Print();//Prints test2
    }
 }

 class Example<T>
 {
    private object Value;

    public Example(T value1)
    {
       this.Value = value1 + "1";
    }

    public Example(string value2)
    {
       this.Value = value2 + "2";
    }

    public void Print()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Value as string);
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to call the generic constructor?

Comment: Yes.  Add a third constructor to class with no parameters.

Comment: I'm not really a C# guy, but what happens if you try the `explicit` keyword on the constructor(s)? My attempt would be on the `string` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use syntax like below with named parameters:

`Example<string> test = new Example<string>(value1: "test");`

The important trick here is to have different parameter names as you currently have, so it will map the right constructor from the parameter name and the code will look like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Example<string> test = new Example<string>(value1: "test");
      test.Print();//Prints test1
   }

class Example<T>
{
    private object Value;

    public Example(T value1)
    {
       this.Value = value1 + "1";
    }

    public Example(string value2)
    {
        this.Value = value2 + "2";
    }

    public void Print()
    {
          Console.WriteLine(Value as string);
       }
    }   
}
```

You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) documentation on named parameters as well.